# Pygame pong ball

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Here I give the speed and the direction to the ball

```
 if collision_ball_pad_l == True:
         print("ball hit the left pad")
         ball_movement = -ball_movement
         if first_collision == 0:
                ball_movement_y = random.choice([1,-1])*speed
         first_collision +=1
```

If ball hits the edge it must change the direction but it prints me that the speed is 0

```
 if collision_ball_shield_u == True:
                print("ball hit the left pad")
                ball_movement_y -= ball_movement_y 
                print (ball_movement_y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change sign of variable - from `+` to `-` or from `-` to `+`

You can do it in one line - see `-` in code

```
 ball_movement_y   =   -ball_movement_y
```